# The type or namespace name 'Stack' could not be found (only with .NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I get an error when i compile this program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class main {
    public static void Main() {
        Stack<int> a;
    }
};
```

with this cmd:

`C:\Users\tomc\Desktop\l>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc test.cs`

I get this error:

> test.cs(12,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Stack' could not be
>           found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However when using this command it builds fine:
`C:\Users\tomc\Desktop\l>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc test.cs`

**Was Stack removed from .NET 4 ? I can't find any indication that it was on MSDN.**

Comment: "Was Stack removed from .NET 4 ?" No.

Comment: The sample you've provided compiles fine in Visual Studio and with the command line.

Comment: If you want to compare the file @YuriyGuts mentioned, here's the one from my installation: http://pastebin.com/hB5KhqcH

Comment: @Stijn i didnt even have that file :S I had to modify your a bit before it would build. mine looks like this now http://pastebin.com/ifCL0AbT

Comment: My first answer has been converted to a comment. I'll try to expand on my answer a little bit and post again in case someone else has this issue.

Comment: @Yuriy Guts: I was just about to undelete your answer after seeing your edit... you didn't have to repost it.

Comment: @BoltClock: Sorry, I wasn't permitted to undelete it by myself, so I posted another one :(  Next time I'll just flag the question for the moderators' attention. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# compiler has a default "configuration" file (called a [response file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3te4xt0y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) located in the .NET Framework installation directory (`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.rsp`). This response file is just a text file that contains a set of compiler command-line switches that are passed by default when compiling a program. You can also specify your own file in addition to the default one (see the link above).

In your case, this file might be missing or corrupted. You can check whether the references to the core libraries are present there. For example, here is the csc.rsp file from my machine:

```
# This file contains command-line options that the C#
# command line compiler (CSC) will process as part
# of every compilation, unless the "/noconfig" option
# is specified. 

# Reference the common Framework libraries
/r:Accessibility.dll
/r:Microsoft.CSharp.dll
/r:System.Configuration.dll
/r:System.Configuration.Install.dll
/r:System.Core.dll
/r:System.Data.dll
/r:System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
/r:System.Data.Linq.dll
/r:System.Data.OracleClient.dll
/r:System.Deployment.dll
/r:System.Design.dll
/r:System.DirectoryServices.dll
/r:System.dll
/r:System.Drawing.Design.dll
/r:System.Drawing.dll
/r:System.EnterpriseServices.dll
/r:System.Management.dll
/r:System.Messaging.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll
/r:System.Security.dll
/r:System.ServiceModel.dll
/r:System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
/r:System.ServiceProcess.dll
/r:System.Transactions.dll
/r:System.Web.dll
/r:System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll
/r:System.Web.Extensions.dll
/r:System.Web.Mobile.dll
/r:System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
/r:System.Web.Services.dll
/r:System.Windows.Forms.Dll
/r:System.Workflow.Activities.dll
/r:System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll
/r:System.Workflow.Runtime.dll
/r:System.Xml.dll
/r:System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

Comment: In my case also I am facing the same error but the file is present where it is supposed to be present and it is not corrupted. What else might be the issue?